# LED controller voltage reduction

Tags: led, led-driver

I have a 12v 4A [LED controller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004961215629.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.186.2e221802e32bhC)[image] and I plan to use it with [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000115950295.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.141.2e221802e32bhC) 3.4v 350mA RGB LEDs[image]

I want to reduce LED's brightness permanently. To do this I need to limit controller's Vout from 0V-12v to some lower voltage. Let's say 0v-3.3v for example.

I successfully achieved this using resistors, but seems like I waste too much energy. I would like to improve my circuit.
[image]
(resistors values are random)

I guess I need something that will reduce controller's output voltage range. Not just convert it to some lower but static value. Seems like a DC-DC converter might be an option. Also I assume LED drivers as an option. Is it possible to use any of them to reduce controller's voltage range? Or they will give me just a static output voltage? How to connect them to my existing circuit?

Comment: All your links are to AliExpress and I have never seen that site provide a datasheet for anything. That's one of the reasons that stuff is cheap and why most of us don't buy from them. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: 1) The pages you linked to are not available to everyone, or at least not me. 2) You need a different "LED Controller". (From what I understand, LED brightness is more reliably varied by controlling the current through them, not the voltage across them.)

Comment: Replacing the resistor with a mosfet and driving with a 555 to create a pwm?

Comment: @FelicePollano or really, anything but a 555 to create a PWM. A 555 is a pretty complicated method of creating a PWM, especially when you need a large range of duty cycles. And you still need series resistors.

Comment: Oleksandr, Professional systems (those I've been exposed to) will design ***three*** separate power supply rails. One for each of the three colors, tailored to provide the least margin that can be managed. Then, a separate system provides current drivers based upon those low-overhead supply rails to set the 100% brightness level. (This may need to be tweaked for each color separately in order to get the designed white balance.) Then brightness is controlled within the 100% level by using PWM.

Comment: He can't use three separate rails because his controller has a single common positive rail. He probably can't go much below 5v either since the regulator on the microcontroller will drop out and the gate drive voltage will be too low.

Comment: @Transistor I've added pictures. It's not a datasheet, but I think this kind of controllers and LED's are well known and some people may recognize it by image. Let me know if any specific data needed.

Comment: @FelicePollano As far as I understand - I may use my controller's Vout as a PWM master? signal. Am I right?

Comment: I and several other people had no trouble understanding this question, so I'm voting to reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a 12v 4A LED controller and I plan to use it with these 3.4v 350mA RGB LEDs.

That's a PWM dimmer. It blinks the LEDs on and off to control average brightness, but you can't use it directly with a bare LED. It needs a resistor to limit current to some maximum value.

> guess I need something that will reduce controller's output voltage range. Not just convert it to some lower but static value. Seems like a DC-DC converter might be an option. Also I found these LED drivers. Is it possible to use any of them to reduce controller's voltage range? Or they will give me just a static output voltage? How to connect them to my existing circuit?

Your PWM controller only works with LEDs that use a current limiting resistor (no drivers), so the best you can do without replacing it is lower the voltage you supply to the PWM device's input. Using a DCDC converter to drop to 5v would improve your efficiency from 3.4/12 (28%) to 3.3/5v (68%). 4v would be even better if you controller can operate that low, but it may not. Alternatively you could stack multiple LEDs in series to get a higher forward voltage.

An LED driver is much more efficient, since they're typically switching regulators that supply the exact voltage required without a resistor, but they won't work with a PWM controller.

Answer (score 3):

tl; dr: this controller uses PWM control, meant for strips which use groups of LEDs wired in series with current limiting resistors. It won't do well with your RGB LED, which needs a current-controlled drive.

The controller you show has a common connection, and varies the average current on each color separately. This connects to a *non-addressable* RGB strip.

It’s more likely that the controller’s common connection is actually to the anodes of the LEDs, which is how strip LEDs tend to be wired.

Details. In a non-addressable RGB (or RGBW) strip, the LEDs are grouped in sections, with several wired in series on each color to make them work at, say, 12V:

[image]

From here: https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/schematic

You’ll see that each set of LEDs in a section has its own current limiting resistor, with a value set for 12V to yield an approximate equal brightness for each color. Common connection is to 12V.

The strip controller you've shown varies the intensity of each color channel by using a separate PWM (12V/0V off and on) for *each* channel. It relies on those resistors in the strip for current limiting.

Simple PWM control like this allows daisy-chaining strips to arbitrary length, *without regards to current*, up to the max the controller can provide (e.g., 4A per channel.)

This PWM-style strip control is 'dumb': it only knows how to do PWM, but not how to regulate current. Again, it's relying on the dropping resistors in the strip to limit the current.

In contrast, the LED you show is a high-power one. It needs a driver that senses and regulates each LED’s current.

You could in theory add series resistors to limit the current (use one for each channel). If we know that the PWM is actually 12V, then we'd use 3 series resistors, calculated as follows:

- Red resistor = (12V - Vf[red])/Imax
- Green resistor = (12V - Vf[green])/Imax
- Blue resistor = (12V - Vf[blue])/Imax

This would get you something, but like your proposal it would be very inefficient, as about 3/4 of the power will be dissipated by the resistors.

A 5V controller would be more sensible if you can locate one, since this would waste less power than dropping from 12V.

What would be ideal is a *current mode* control per channel, that uses a step-down (buck) output. A quick look doesn't seem to reveal an easy Bluetooth-capable solution, but you may have better luck with more digging.

It may also be possible to use a strip controller PWM output to control 3 separate buck modules, one for each color channel. This would be more efficient than dropping resistors. Example here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13705 This module supports 350mA or 700mA fixed current, and has PWM control input.